# What is the fastest way to check if two given numbers are coprime?

Tags: algorithm, number-theory, greatest-common-divisor

One way is to calculate their **gcd** and check if it is 1.

Is there some faster way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Euclidean algorithm (computes `gcd`) is very fast. When two numbers are drawn uniformly at random from `[1, n]`, the average number of steps to compute their `gcd` is `O(log n)`. The average computation time required for each step is quadratic in the number of digits.

There are alternatives that perform somewhat better (i.e., each step is subquadratic in the number of digits), but they are only effective on very large integers. See, for example, [On Schönhage's algorithm and subquadratic integer gcd computation](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/archive/sgcd.pdf).

Comment: I'd like to comment that it's a bit coarse to measure complexity of arithmetic algorithms without taking costs of arithmetic operations into account.

Comment: The worstcase # of steps is O(log n) as well, when two numbers are successive entries in the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Pavel Shved: I did take the cost into consideration. cf. the sentence "The average computation time required for each step is quadratic in the number of digits."

Answer (score 7):

if you're running on a machine for which division/remainder is significantly more expensive than shifts, consider [binary GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm).

Comment: Just implemented this in f# and its more than 2x faster than traditional Euclid's GCD, cannot give exact numbers as there is other code poluting my measurements, however its > 2x faster.  Good find Jason.

Comment: Update: Did better numbers in isolation:  Iterations: 100000, Euclid Took: 27ms, Binary GCD Tool: 11ms (so that's about 40%  of Euclid). Awesome!

Comment: @gatapia Care to do a `gist` of your F# ?

Comment: @javadba check out [here](https://github.com/gatapia/guidos_proj_euler/blob/b1eff7cfc7da6c2a895a782163411f2999763b0b/ProjEuler/Utils.fs) last function called binGcd